# Displaying a popup when user enters a page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, popup

I want to display a little disclaimer when a user goes onto a certain webpage. I am currently using window.addEventListener load but this only displays the popup when the website is refreshed on the page.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import DisclaimerPopup from "./DisclaimerPopup";

export class LearnTheBasics extends Component {
    static displayName = LearnTheBasics.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ShowDisclaimerPopup: false,
            profileData: [],
            error: null
        };
    }

    toggleDisclaimerPopup() {
        this.setState({
            showDisclaimerPopup: !this.state.showDisclaimerPopup
        });
    }
       
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('load', this.toggleDisclaimerPopup.bind(this))
    }
    render() {

        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.showDisclaimerPopup ?
                    <DisclaimerPopup
                        closePopup={this.toggleDisclaimerPopup.bind(this)}
                    /> : null
                }
                
                <h1>Learn The Basics</h1>
                <br />
                <h3> Add pop up disclaimer</h3>

                <p>ADD list here of different basics hacks to learn. (css, SQLi etc)</p>
                
                
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the code for the page. DisclaimerPopup is just the content that is displayed. I did tinker with useEffect and useState but I couldn't get this to work.

Updated code to useEffect

```
import React, { useEffect, useState, Component } from 'react';
import DisclaimerPopup from "./DisclaimerPopup";

export class LearnTheBasics extends Component {
    static displayName = LearnTheBasics.name;

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            ShowDisclaimerPopup: false,
            profileData: [],
            error: null       
        };
    }

    toggleDisclaimerPopup() {
        this.setState({
            showDisclaimerPopup: !this.state.showDisclaimerPopup
        });
    }

        
    render() {
        function LearnTheBasics() {
            let [setPopup] = React.useState(false);

            useEffect(() => {
                setPopup(true);
            }, [])
        }
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.showDisclaimerPopup ?
                    <DisclaimerPopup
                        closePopup={this.toggleDisclaimerPopup.bind(this)}
                    /> : null
                }
                
                <h1>Learn The Basics</h1>
                <br />
                <h3> Add pop up disclaimer</h3>

                <p>ADD list here of different basics hacks to learn. (css, SQLi etc)</p>
                
                
            </div>
        );
    }
```

Comment: Change state inside `componentDidMount` like `showPopUp: true` and show your popup if this state is true and `showPopUp: false` when modal is closed.

Comment: You're working too hard.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using class-based component, you can use `withRouter` HOC and wrap the child component in it. That will allow you to have access to `this.props.location.pathname`, now in your `componentDidMount()` function, check for the exact pathname you are looking for, and set the local state to be true if it matches and consequently render the disclaimer popup.

You can read about `withRouter` more [here](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter)

Answer (score 0):

Making popup as stateful and using useEffect.  I have set the deps array empty so that the disclaimer pops on for the first time, the user enters the page.

```
function LearnTheBasics() {
    let [popup, setPopup] = React.useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        setPopup(true);
    }, [])

    return (
      <div>
        {popup ? 'popup called': 'dont call the method'}
      </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried to implement this but It keeps throwing me errors

Comment: can you share them here

Comment: Managed to fix the errors but no popup displays at all now I have updated the post with the new code